# Reading variables from a different fortran code

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have two fortran files `A.sub` and `B.f90`. `A` has tons of subroutines while `B` is the executable program. `A` runs 100 times inside `B`. B.f90 looks like this:

---

```
do i=1,step_total

    <lots of statements>

enddo

include 'A.sub'
```

---

The variable `step_total` is defined as 100 in a separate file. I need to read this variable inside `A.sub`. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So you don't have *two* files as stated in the question, but *three* files?

Comment: Yes you are right. There are many files from which data is being read in the main program

Comment: Have a look at the `module`.

Comment: how is the file that have `step_total` declared? Is it a module (so you and `use` it and have acces to the variable by host association?

Comment: step_total is declared in a common block in a separate text file C and it is read from a text file D

Comment: I have understood my mistake! Parts of A.sub were being run only once instead of 100. I just added a loop where required and used the loop index. It works now. Much thanks to those who tried to help. Apologies for not realising my mistake earlier.